# Find objects in a list where one property contains duplicate values

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following model class:

```
public class DuplicateTags
{
    public string VMName { set; get; }
    public string shortName { set; get; }
}
```

It is being populated as follow:

```
int tempindex = tempvmname.IndexOf('-');
duplicateTagsInDisplayName.Add(new DuplicateTags 
{ 
    VMName = tempvmname, 
    shortName = tempvmname.Substring(0, tempindex)
});
```

Now I want to display the list items that have duplicate shortName?

Comment: what do you mean by a two-dimensional list?

Comment: @jeroenh a list that have two string objects ...

Comment: @dotctor i could find find a way to do so ... otherwise i would have provided my code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is no such thing as a "two dimensional list" in .Net. You have a list of objects of type `DuplicateTags`, where `DuplicateTag` is a class having 2 properties.

Now, to solve your problem, I would suggest you learn about LINQ.

Specifically, you can use `GroupBy` for this:

```
var groupedByShortName = duplicateTagsInDisplayName.GroupBy(x => x.shortName);
var duplicates = groupedByShortName.Where(item => item.Count() > 1);
foreach (var duplicate in duplicates)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} occurs {1} times", duplicate.Key, duplicate.Count);
    foreach (var item in duplicate)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("   {0}", item.VMName);
    } 
}
```

Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results

Answer (score 5):

You can use linq to get duplicate values

```
var duplicateShortNames = duplicateTagsInDisplayName
    .GroupBy(x => x.shortName) // items with same shorName are grouped to gether
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1) // filter groups where they have more than one memeber
    .Select(x => x.Key) // select shortName from these groups
    .ToList(); // convert it to a list
```

then you can check if any of your items are in duplicates and display them

```
foreach (var item in duplicateTagsInDisplayName)
{
    if (duplicateShortNames.Contains(item.shortName))
        Console.WriteLine(item.VMName + item.shortName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var list = new []{ 
                new{ VMName = "a", shortName = "sn1" },
                new{ VMName = "a", shortName = "sn2" },
                new{ VMName = "b", shortName = "sn1" },
};

var groupedList = list.GroupBy(x => x.shortName)
                           .Select(x => 
                                        new{ 
                                             ShortName = x.Key, 
                                             Items = x,                                             
                                             Count = x.Count()
                                           }
                                  );

var onlyDuplicates = groupedList.Where(x => x.Count > 1);
```